# Run VmwarePlayer service automatically also logoff our system

Tags: vmware-player

i want run my vmwareplayer always in background,becuase i am install this Vmwareplayer in our server this is shared my multiple persions.even system is logedoff that service must run this is our requirement any one pls provide suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You want VMware Server http://www.vmware.com/products/server/overview.html rather than Player.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is running Linux then edit the file`/etc/rc.local` and add the following line:

```
/etc/rc.d/vmware.d/vmware start
```